# How can I get the directory name depends on os.File in go?

Tags: file, go, directory

`go version go1.17 linux/amd64`

The dirInfo in os.File is private , is there any way to get it ?

Tried google , look over the official doc

Comment: A file itself does not have a directory. How did you get the `os.File` in the first place?

Comment: I get the `os.File` by relative path which I don't want to save, and I want to get it's absolute path.

Comment: Then use [`filepath.Abs`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Abs) to convert the relative path. A file alone has no single absolute path; it may have multiple, or not even exist in the filesystem.

Comment: That didn't help with my problem.

Comment: Then you need to better explain what the problem is. It's up to you to know what the file path is, the file cannot tell you.

Comment: OK, I got it. There is no way to get the file's abs path only by it self. But I think it's kind of strange.